# Search XML feed's description against a keyword from database

Tags: mysql, match, space, against

I'm working on a project where I use XML feeds to get input. I have to filter the items which title and description that matches specific keywords. If an item contains smart phone in title or description, I have to add that item in database under the category "Smart phone".

The query I use here is
$title = $item=>title;
$desc = $item->description;
SELECT `cid` FROM `tbl_keyword` WHERE MATCH(`keyword`) AGAINST ('".$title." ".$desc."' IN 
BOOLEAN MODE);

Query returns value but it gets other rows from database like smart watch,smart toys.

I want to know, how to include space based search.
Query have to match the exact keyword.

table looks like
id  cid  keyword
1  6  smart phone
2  6  iphone
3  7  smart watch

When i get a title as "Smart phones are not essential", query should return only the cid 6.

How to implement it.?

Answer (score 0):

As I know , you can't just search the whole sentence(Smart phones are not essential) against the db to get that exact result .

**Two ways to do this :**

1.**(Recommended)**You can just break the sentence with space ("Smart", "Phone", "are", "not", "essential")and then apply the following query

**select * from tbl_keyword where keyword like "%smart%" or keyword like "%phones%" or keyword like "%are%" or keyword like "%not%" or keyword like "%essential%"**

This query will output list of possible entries from the database. From this you will need to compare the result with your query sentence using your programming language.

---

2.This way will output the entry directly from the database (but this may rule out some of the important entries at worst case).

Breakdown the sentence into single word like this ("Smart", "Phones", "are", "not", "essential")

And then break this sentence with two words like this ("Smart Phones", "Phone are", "are not", "not essential","essential Smart","Smart are","Smart not","Phone not")

And use both of this to retrieve entries from the database (This process will just narrow down the filter)

**select * from tbl_keyword where (keyword like "%smart%" or keyword like "%phone%" or keyword like "%are%" or keyword like "%not%" or keyword like "%essential%") and (keyword like "%smart phones%" or keyword like "%phones are%" or keyword like "%are not%" or keyword like "%not essentials%" or keyword like "%essentials smart%")**

Hope this will help you ...

Comment: I ll implement as you mentioned\